# How to record a macro to sum dynamical column?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

Data in `tom.xsl`.
[image]

Record a macro ,name it `cal`,shortcut key is `ctrl+a`.
[image]

Data in `peter.xsl`.
[image]

What i expect when to call macro `cal` in `peter.xsl`.
[image]

What i really get when to call macro `cal` in `peter.xsl`.
[image]

How to fix my macro to make it sum dynamical column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it dynamic, you must find the bottom of the data and place the formula below it.  Before:

[image]

The code:

```
Sub scrapy()
    Dim BottomOfTable As Long

    BottomOfTable = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Cells(BottomOfTable + 1, "A").Value = "total_score"
    Cells(BottomOfTable + 1, "B").Formula = "=SUM(B2:B" & BottomOfTable & ")"
End Sub
```

The result:

[image]